# Existence of closed and intersecting geodesics on a compact manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, classical-mechanics

Consider a compact, not simply connected manifold which is the configuration space of a mechanical system (e.g. a torus, the configuration space of a linear double pendulum).

Some well-known theorems say that on such manifold there exists at least one (closed) geodesic for *every* closed curves homotopy class (provided the total energy of the system is high enough).

What puzzles me is that (in general) such geodesics could in fact intersect *transversally*. Either with themselves, either with one another.

Does this mean that also in phase space such intersection could occur?

Comment: Could you further un-mix the situation? A mechanical system usually is Hamiltonian, is defined by its energy function. It lives on the co-tangent bundle, which with the canonical 1-form constitutes a symplectic manifold. Geodesics are defined for a Riemannian metric, which is a sufficiently smooth s.p.d. 2-form on the tangent bundle. The geodesic equations are then ODE on the tangent bundle. What do you mean with "closed"? The cited examples are compact. So in the end you could be asking about closed geodesics on compact Riemannian manifolds.

Comment: Yes, and this already happens on a torus: thinking of a (flat) torus as a square with sides identified, cut the square in half first horizontally and then vertically. Why does this possibility puzzle you?

Comment: From the moment I've written this question I've arrived to exactly the same conclusion @QiaochuYuan, so thank you indeed for your valuable confirm...Above this, my conclusion is that whenever the geodesics on configuration space _could_ "cross intersect", the corresponding trajectories in phase space could not (violating classical mechanics determinism otherwise)...do you agree on that too?

Comment: Yes, the phase space trajectories don't intersect.